# Understanding Model Relationship using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have currently studying the eloquent orm relationship in laravel, right now I just reading the documentation of laravel how to differentiate the One to One, One to Many and Many to Many. Today I create products and product categories. however I have a single question why does the product categories column in the table is not included to the output: I will share to you guys the sample model that I created today.

I have here product categories model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product_category extends Model
{
    //
    // protected $table = 'product_categories';
    public function getProductsRelation() {
        return $this->hasMany(product::class,'product_categorie_id','id');
    }
}
```

For my product model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'products';
}
```

My Output:

[image: output]

**Why this column not included to the output:**

[image: problem]

Comment: `App\product_category::find(1)` will return product category record [id=1]. `App\product_category::find(1)->getProductsRelation` will return only products which are related to `category 1`. If you need both records in a single object use `with()` method. `App\product_category::with('getProductsRelation')->find(1);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want both records in a single Query use with().

```
App\product_category::with('getProductsRelation')->find(1);
```